# Can you return a view from spring mvc as a string for an ajax call?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I am trying to do the following....

With an ajax, I call a service (a get method) , that services get the info and all...

What I want to do is , with my ajax (not json, is a GET only, very simple), get as result the view (I bet as a string or html) generated from my method previously called...

here is the method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  ModelAndView getInfo(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    //do some calls to my services and return it to fill out the view

    mav.setViewName("dialogContent");
    mav.addObject("myObject", object);
    return mav;     
}
```

Ive also tried using the **@ResponseBody** annotation...

So far, it works, only if at the view template there is only HTML code, but I need to show info sent throught "myObject" , I get an error like it is null or undefined. Is this possible? or any similar way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the object in the SessionScope if it is serializable and the retrieve it in the view, otherwise I cant see this working, the object is not part of the same request thus it is not accessible from your calling page.